# Editing open-source libraries

Tags: c++, opengl, open-source, glm-math

I'm currently developing a C++ library to make the lives of my OpenGL game development team easier. I'm using GLM for handling maths.

Assuming I credit the original creators appropriately and leave any license information in the files, is it okay to rename the GLM namespace to match the namespace I'm using in my library? This will make using the library in the end much cleaner, without exposing multiple different libraries/namespaces to the users.

If this isn't legal/ethical, is there anything I can do to add an alias to the namespace and only expose the alias?

Thanks.

Comment: `namespace your_namespace { using namespace glm; ... }`?

Comment: That's not a programming problem as required here. Asking for legacy problems is off-topic.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's not so much a legacy but a legality question. And given the fact that legalese essentially is a form of weakly formalized programming written in prose (`if` person does $this `and` $that `then` $law is violated), so I think it's actually a programming question ;)

Comment: @datenwolf https://www.reddit.com/r/trees/comments/30esh8/unicode_weed/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing questions are off topic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues instead of directly about programming. [[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)] for details and the [[help]] for more.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it is not a direct, programming related issue, but rather about licensing. You may be able to get an answer at [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read their on-topic page too. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GLM License](http://glm.g-truc.net/copying.txt):

It says:

> [...] to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software [...]

This is the only condition:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

And one restriction:

> By making use of the Software for military purposes, you choose to make a
>    Bunny unhappy.

So you can rename the namespace as you like.

**Don't use it for millitary purpose if you care about bunnies.**

Comment: Thank you for the help. Since this is the first time we're making commercial projects with some open-source libraries, I had to make sure.

Comment: How could that be enforceable? So is it flip or is it a true restriction on military use?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could always qualify a namespace:

```
namespace myName{
    using namespace X;
}
```

Which would make `myName::item` the same as `X::item`

Comment: That would mean the user can use `myName::item` as well as `X::item`. I only want access to `myName::item`, and never `X::item`.

Comment: @DingusKhan I understand, but if you couldn't change the namespace because of the license, then qualifying it would work instead.